# Wrapper function helper

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Let’s imagine I have a function to handle `requestIdleCallBack` and a greetings function :

```
const requestIdle = (func, timeout) => {
  if ('requestIdleCallback' in window) {
    timeout = timeout ? {timeout} : null
    return window.requestIdleCallback(func, timeout)
  } else {
    func()
    return null
  }
}

const greeting = ({firstName, lastName}) => {
  console.log(`Hello ${firstName} ${lastName}`)
}
```

Then, I want to call the `greeting` function in a idle time. So the code is :

```
const requestIdleAndGreet = ({firstName, lastName}) => {
  requestIdle(() => greeting({firstName, lastName}))
}
```

Here is my question : is there a vanilla/jquery/lodash... helper which could act as a 'wrapping' function for `greeting({firstName, lastName})`? Something like this :

```
const wrapper = (func, ...args) => {
  return () => {
    func(...args)
  }
}

const requestIdleAndGreet = ({firstName, lastName}) => {
  requestIdle(wrapper(greeting, {firstName, lastName}))
}
```

Comment: Is it just for aesthetic reasons, or why do you want to wrap it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard `bind` method can do this:

```
const requestIdleAndGreet = ({firstName, lastName}) => 
    requestIdle(greeting.bind(null, {firstName, lastName}));
```

The first argument to `bind` is the `this` value for the bound function, the rest bind the parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I didn't knew this use of the `bind` method